How to take backup when laptop keeps restarting due to blue screen error
I have a Lenovo laptop with Win11. Suddenly it started malfunctioning. It boots properly, and all other functionality works fine. However, after few minutes(~3-4min) it shows blue screen error.

I thought this is a software issue, hence I have reset the OS, but it did not make any difference. It leads me to the conclusion that this might be the hardware problem. But before going to visit service center, I need to take backup of all my drive data, and here is the problem.
I can't take backup as laptop keeps restarting after few minutes, so is there any way to take data backup?
Edit: Added EventViwer Logs





Older crash logs


There are many more logs, can't add all of them there.

Have you tried to boot into safe-mode? Is it happening over there too?

Some backup software boot into its own OS and allow you to take a backup there to a remote destination, such as external disk or network share. Acronis true image can do this, but there is other software too. Alternatively, open the computer and take the disk out, connect it to another computer and make the backup there. You can also see if you can find something like Hirens boot dvd, which contain backup solutions on their bootable media.

@Netan, just tried it, safe mode works, thanks! I'm wondering...does it really hardware problem or something else!

if safe mode works, not all drivers are loaded, so it may be a driver problem or hardware that is not loaded. Also some software don't load that may have a kernel driver, such as virus scanner. Because it takes 3 to 4 minutes for the problem to occur, this suggests its not major hardware. Maybe a keyboard, mouse or usb stick?

BTW, it's handy to have a bootable rescue USB, for making full disk image or trying repairs when the system won't boot at all. As @LPChip states, there's Acronis, and also Marium Rescue Environment, Hiren's Boot CD PE, and others.

@Div turn on the computer as normal. Wait for it to shut down and make sure you note the exact time, to the second. Then enter safe-mode, there enter event viewer and look in the last events before the time of the restart/shutdown.

It may not scream "error" but you can share a screenshot and we can help you understand what happened ( maybe, for example, the computer recognized a USB device or tried to enter sleep? Could be anything haha )

Regarding backups, I strongly support backing up C:\users\username. You probably won't need much of anything else, unless you have saves of files within Program Files or AppData ( like... notepad++ unsaved documents? Again, there are many examples )

To test your windows installation from scratch, you can replace the SSD and install windows onto the new one, while keeping the older installation physically outside of the PC, so it won't be disturbed, even by accident, when formatting and installing windows.

Thanks! @Netan I will check event viewer and will let you know

@Netan it's also hard to capture the screen, as it is too quick.

@Div is event viewer too fast? Sorry I don't understand

@Netan, Added logs into the question

Do you run McAfee as your antivirus?

@Netan, nope. It was inbuilt installed, I uninstalled long time ago.

I really cannot determine that just from these pictures, but the first one seems to complain about a connectivity problem to the CPU. That's NOT normal and might indicate a problem with the processor. It is pretty old, though ( Xeon E3 1200/1500, ain't it? )

To backup the computer, you can remove the SSD and plug it into another computer. There, just copy it's content into another drive. BTW, have you tried to boot something like "Hiren's Bootable CD"? If the linux-system will run normally, then it might just suggest a problem with your Windows installation.

I haven't tried bootable CD, but will give a try, thanks@Netan

@Netan I did try with Hiren's Bootable CD, booting OS from it doesn't throw any error, and works fine.

@Netan: This got resolved with the fresh win installation. Thank you!
Though scanning any hardware problems.

To achieve a more consistant experience, always try safe mode.
To diagnose this further, there are several ways to go, but searching in the Event Viewer for the exact time of the BSOD will show you the last things the OS did, which led to the crash.
For example, maybe a USB device got disconnected and reconnected momentairily, or the PC tried to use the connected printer, etc.

Try to boot with a USB drive, something like Hiren's Bootable CD. If that works, then there is no issues related to hardware. You can take a backup of the data.
I have installed the fresh version of Windows OS and it resolved the issue.
